# Append row data with two condition using JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, jquery-ui

I am trying to appending data with two conditions. It is not working properly::

Table 1: there are 2 field- a) input for employee id and b) drop-down for salary type

Table 2: Want to append data here with the condition of employee id and salary type

Condition would be prevent repeat data with id and salarytype. It is not working properly: for example I select

123   Basic
123   Normal 
124   Basic
124   Normal => here it is not working. I want to add this row but failed to do that. I need to add row data and check employee id and salary type to prevent repeating.

## Html

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> 
                <input id="empid" placeholder="employeid">   
            </td>
            <td> 
                    <select id="salarytype">
                        <option value="Basic"> Basic</option> 
                        <option value="Normal"> Normal</option>
                    </select>    
            </td>
            <td><span id="button_add"> Add </span>  </td>
        </tr>
</table>


<table>
    <tbody id="test">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

## JavaScript

```
    var addedEmployeeId = [];
var addedSalaryType = [];

  $("#button_add").click(function () {

    ///getting data from a table 
    var tableData = $(this).closest("tr").find("td input").map(function () {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    //getting salary type by dropdown
    var e = document.getElementById("salarytype");
    var salarytype = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    var empid = document.getElementById("empid").value;
    var addedEmpid = $.trim(tableData[0]);

    //checking value in array
    var index = $.inArray(addedEmpid, addedEmployeeId);
    var salaryArray = $.inArray(salarytype, addedSalaryType);

    //appending data to another table
    if (index >= 0 && salaryArray >= 0) {
      alert("You already added Employee And Salary Type");
      exit;
    } else {
      if (empid == "") {
        alert("Please add Employee ID");
        exit;
      } else {
        $("#test").append(
          "<tr><td><input name='' value='" + $.trim(tableData[0]) + "' style='width: 120px;' readonly > </td><td><input value='" + salarytype + "' style='width: 100px;' readonly ></td></tr>");

        addedEmployeeId.push(addedEmpid);
        addedSalaryType.push(salarytype);
            }
        }   

    });
```

Helps are highly appreciated.

Comment: Here is jsfiddle:: http://jsfiddle.net/selimppc/5gEYM/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the matched items in both arrays are at the same index..

Simply looping through the array as follows will solve the issue (assuming both have the same length):

```
for (var i = 0; i < addedEmployeeId.length; i++) {
    if (addedEmployeeId[i] == empid && addedSalaryType[i] == salarytype) {
        flag = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/5gEYM/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

**JS**

```
   var addedEmployeeId = [];
var addedSalaryType = [];

  $("#button_add").click(function () {

    ///getting data from a table 
    var tableData = $(this).closest("tr").find("td input").map(function () {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    //getting salary type by dropdown
    var e = document.getElementById("salarytype");
    var salarytype = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    var empid = document.getElementById("empid").value;
    var addedEmpid = $.trim(tableData[0]);

    //checking value in array
    var index = $.inArray(addedEmpid, addedEmployeeId);
    var salaryArray = $.inArray(salarytype, addedSalaryType);
var booltype=true;
    //appending data to another table
      $('#test tr').each(function(midex,mval){
          var empids=$(mval).find('td:eq(0)').find('input').val();
          var saltype=$(mval).find('td:eq(1)').find('input').val();
          if(parseInt(empids)==parseInt(addedEmpid) && (saltype==salarytype)){
                  booltype=false;

          }
      });
    if (booltype==false) {
      alert("You already added Employee And Salary Type");

    } else {
      if (empid == "") {
        alert("Please add Employee ID");

      } else {
        $("#test").append(
          "<tr><td><input name='' value='" + $.trim(tableData[0]) + "' style='width: 120px;' readonly > </td><td><input value='" + salarytype + "' style='width: 100px;' readonly ></td></tr>");

        addedEmployeeId.push(addedEmpid);
        addedSalaryType.push(salarytype);
            }
        }   

    });
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/eu38K/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I would use object structure for this job instead, it would simplify handling of it:

**JavaScript:**

```
var employees = {};

$("#button_add").click(function () {

   //getting data from a table 
   var tableData = $(this).closest("tr").find("td input").map(function () {
       return $(this).val();
   }).get();

   //getting salary type by dropdown
   var e = document.getElementById("salarytype");
   var salarytype = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

   var empid = document.getElementById("empid").value;
   var addedEmpid = $.trim(tableData[0]);

   // if employee added previous with addedEmpid and given salary, dont add!
   if(employees.hasOwnProperty(addedEmpid) && employees[addedEmpid].hasOwnProperty(salarytype)) {

      alert("You already added Employee And Salary Type");  

   } else if(empid == "") {

      alert("Please add Employee ID");

   } else {

      // if employee id unknown, we create the object
      if(!employees.hasOwnProperty(addedEmpid)) {
          employees[addedEmpid] = {};   
      }

      // adding salaratype for this id
      employees[addedEmpid][salarytype] = true;

      $("#test").append("<tr><td><input name='' value='" + $.trim(tableData[0]) + "' style='width: 120px;' readonly > </td><td><input value='" + salarytype + "' style='width: 100px;' readonly ></td></tr>");

      // for debugging...
      console.log(employees);

   }

});
```

When you have done adding all your given employees, for example:

```
123 Basic
123 Normal
124 Basic
124 Normal
```

Your resulting `employees` object will have the following structure:

```
{
   123: {
      Basic: true,
      Normal: true
   },
   124: {
      Basic: true,
      Normal: true
   }
}
```

This way you can even add another types easily than just `Basic` and `Normal`

See fiddle example, it works: **[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gEYM/2/)**

Comment: @selim Accepting it as solution or vote-up could help future readers, thnx :)